# Using same EventHandler for MouseEvent & KeyEvent in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling, javafx-8, eventhandler

I'm new to Java programming, so this question may sound stupid to many here. I'm trying to get myself comfortable with JavaFX Event handling mechanism.

I'm developing a GUI where I want a button to perform the same function when it's clicked and also when the Enter key is pressed.

Can I do the following?

```
public class ButtonHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>
{
somefunction();
}
```

And then use it for both KeyEvent & MouseEvent

```
button.setOnMouseClicked(new ButtonHandler);
button.setOnKeyPressed(new ButtonHandler);
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't need any information from the specific event (such as coordinates of the mouse, or the key that was pressed), you can do

```
EventHandler<Event> handler = event -> {
    // handler code here...
};
```

and then

```
button.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, handler);
button.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, handler);
```

Of course, you can also just delegate the actual work to a regular method:

```
button.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
    doHandle();
});
button.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
    doHandle();
});

// ...

private void doHandle() {
    // handle event here...
}
```

Comment: So when I want a button event to be handled only when ENTER is pressed, can I not go with what you suggested?

Comment: No, but you can just delegate the actual work to another method. See update.